# How to make `\bm{<number>}` work with `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` and pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, bm

I get bold `0` as exected when I compile the following code with lualatex. 
However, I get normal (not bold) `0` with pdflatex.
 Is there any workaround to get bold `0` with pdflatex?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} 
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
0$0\bm{0}$ % OK with lualatex, but not with pdflatex
\end{document}
```

My environment is

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
bm: 2017/01/16
newtx: 1.515 2017-01-22
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass `libertine` as an option to `newtxmath` it then uses the semi-bold weight in mathematics for bold characters.  However, you have not loaded a text font, so the default Computer Modern fonts are being used for numbers etc. in mathematics, but there is no semi-bold weight version of the Computer Modern fonts. A work around is to add a font substitution instruction

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{sb}{n}{<->ssub * cmr/b/n}{}
```

which gives the desired result, as the document below demonstrates, by substituting the `sb` weight by the `b` weight. But really you should be loading an appropriate text font to match the mathematics, e.g. just issue

```
\usepackage{libertine}
```

before loading `newtxmath` instead.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{sb}{n}{<->ssub * cmr/b/n}{}

\begin{document}

Testing some mathematics \( x = y^2 = \int_0^1 2y\,dy \).

Testing some bold symbols \( \bm{v} = (0,0,0) = \bm{0} \).

\end{document}
```

Incidentally you can see exactly which characters are being printed by issuing `\showoutput` in your file.

Comment: +1 I was just writing same thing:-) but what I'm not clear about is why     `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` left the math digits using cm, that seems.. unexpected?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The newtx documentation states that "it uses the text font settings to define how operators, numbers, math accents, \mathrm, \mathbf etc. are rendered."

Comment: low blow that, reading documentation:-) I sort of assumed it would do that but libertine option would tell it to use libertine not cm, but I never looked at any doc:-)